# Induce IPython notebook output cell programmatically from a different source file

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Suppose there is a Python file `myfile.py`. The contents of the file can be treated as if it was pasted into a single cell in an IPython notebook and then executed (and any output generated should be generated in the notebook).

Is it possible to programmatically cause this to happen? That is, I want to invoke something like "python myfile.py" and have the result be that a notebook is launched, a tab pops open, and *only the output that would have resulted from myfile.py* is displayed already in the notebook.

I'm specifically looking to avoid the case where the .py file is "turned into a notebook" and the code-to-be-executed appears as an input cell.

The idea is for invocation of this .py file to function like a web app -- so just the output should pop up in a notebook. The notebook's kernel should still be operating though, in case there is interactivity that must post callbacks to the code from the .py file.

Each piece seems to exist in IPython already (interactive widgets, conversion to notebook, even just using Popen to launch the notebook) -- but it's unclear how to launch from a plain .py file in such a way that only the output appears.

Here is an attempt:

```
import sys
import subprocess
from IPython.nbformat import current as nbf

# Parse the output cell needed from the file
py_file_name = sys.argv[1] 
with open(py_file_name, 'r') as py_file:
    py_code = py_file.read()

# Set an input cell and invoke it.
nb = nbf.new_notebook()
cells = [nbf.new_code_cell(py_code)]
nb['worksheets'].append(nbf.new_worksheet(cells=cells))

# Store the result into a notebook.
notebook_name = py_file_name + '.ipynb'
with open(notebook_name, 'w') as f:
    nbf.write(nb, f, 'ipynb')

# Launch a new IPython notebook kernel
subprocess.call(["ipython", "-c", "'%run {}'".format(notebook_name)])
```

This isn't ideal -- since it still requires me to populate the *input* part of a cell, and then to actually open the file and execute it.

Even so, I get an error when I use the `%run` option at the bottom, like this:

```
ely@eschaton:~$ python launcher.py myfile1.py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/ely/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, *where)
    202             else:
    203                 filename = fname
--> 204             __builtin__.execfile(filename, *where)

/home/ely/myfile1.py.ipynb in <module>()
      8     {
      9      "cell_type": "code",
---> 10      "collapsed": false,
     11      "input": [
     12       "import numpy as np\n",

NameError: name 'false' is not defined
```

Comment: i have the same problem right now.. without "anaconda" it was working. In production, without anaconda still works..

Answer (score 0):

just remove anaconda, somehow it is causing this problem. To remove it, just do a `rm -rf ~/anaconda` and try it again to do `%run`  (assuming that you have all pandas/ipython requirements)